# Render product view into without full product view controller request

Tags: layout

Is it possible to render the product view block/template without either performing an ajax request or full product request?

I would like to do something similar to:

```
$productViewHtml = Mage::app()->getLayout()->createBlock('product.info')->setProduct(1)->toHtml();
```

For starters, this code doesnt work, therefore i need to resolve that.  But the main problem i can see are that different product types require different layout handles which are set in the controller.  I can not find any way to achieve.

Comment: Have you tried using the layout XML equivalent of the code you posted, using `<action method="setProduct"><value>1</value</action>`?

Answer (score 1):

To do this, you shold replicate `viewAction` of `Mage_Catalog_ProductController`. This action uses `Mage_Catalog_Helper_Product_View`, see it's functions:

```
public function prepareAndRender($productId, $controller, $params = null)
{
    //product initalization
}

public function initProductLayout($product, $controller)
{
    //most of update handles applies here
}
```

I am sure you can do this, do some research.